# Differentiation to get $F'(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives

I have $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) &\text{ if } x\neq 0, \\
      0 & \text{ if }x=0. 
   \end{cases}$$ and define $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t) dt$. I want to show that $F'(0)=f(0)$.

My idea is $$F'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(h)-F(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\int_0^h \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) dx}{h}$$ and using a change of variables $t=\frac{1}{x}$ we have $$F'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\int_{\frac{1}{h}}^\infty\frac{\sin t}{t^2} dt}{h}.$$

I am not sure how to get this equal to $0$ now? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the statement you want to prove is true.

Comment: @NinadMunshi So you mean it is simply not true that $F'(0)=f(0)$ or I just made some mistake in calculation?

Comment: @NinadMunshi One thought was I might be able to use monotone/bounded/dominated convergence theorem to help me here but I am not sure if that would work.

Comment: Take the function $\sin\left(\log |x|\right)+\cos\left(\log |x|\right)$ which has an antiderivative of $x\sin\left(\log |x|\right)$ (filled in with $0$ at $0$ in both cases). We can easily define the antiderivative function in the same way in this problem, but taking the derivative by definition gives $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x\sin(\log |x|) - 0}{x- 0} = \lim_{x\to 0}\sin (\log |x|)$$ which clearly does not exist.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I do not understand how your comment relates to this problem since this is not the same function I am looking at?

Comment: The derivative of an antiderivative does not always exist? I thought that would have been made clear by an explicit example

Comment: @NinadMunshi Here $F^\prime(0)$ exists. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Consider

$$G(x) = \int_x^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t^2} \ dt$$ that is well defined on $[1, \infty)$. By integration by part, you get

$$G(x)=\frac{\cos x}{x^2} - 2 \int_x^\infty \frac{\cos t}{t^3} \ dt$$ and

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} x G(x) = 0$$ as $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{\cos x}{x} = 0$ and

$$\left\vert \int_x^\infty \frac{\cos t}{t^3} \ dt \right\vert \le  \int_x^\infty \frac{1}{t^3} \ dt = \frac{1}{2x^2}.$$

Then you indeed get the desired result

$$F^\prime(0)=f(0)=0$$ as

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\int_{\frac{1}{h}}^\infty\frac{\sin t}{t^2} dt}{h} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} x G(x) = 0.$$

Comment: Makes sense! I just tried it out, and you can do the same integration by parts on the original integral so that the limit is valid from both directions

Answer (score 0):

Since

\begin{align}
\displaystyle\left|\dfrac{\int_0^h\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\mathrm{d}x}{h}\right|&=\left|\dfrac1h\int_0^h\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\mathrm{d}x\right|=\\
&=\left|\dfrac1h\int_0^h\!\left[D\left(x^2\cos\left(\dfrac1x\right)\right)-2x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]\mathrm{d}x\right|\leqslant\\
&\leqslant\left|\dfrac1h\int_0^h\!\!D\left(x^2\cos\left(\dfrac1x\right)\right)\mathrm{d}x\right|+\left|\dfrac1h\int_0^h 2x\cos\left(\dfrac1x\right)\mathrm{d}x\right|=\\
&=\left|\dfrac1h\cdot h^2\cos\left(\dfrac1h\right)\right|+\left|\dfrac1h\int_0^h 2x\cos\left(\dfrac1x\right)\mathrm{d}x\right|\leqslant\\
&\leqslant\big|h\big|+\left|\dfrac1h\int_0^h\left|2x\cos\left(\dfrac1x\right)\right|\mathrm{d}x\right|\leqslant\\
&\leqslant\big|h\big|+\left|\dfrac1h\int_0^h \big|2x\big|\mathrm{d}x\right|=\\
&=\big|h\big|+\left|\dfrac1h\cdot\mathrm{sign}(h)\cdot h^2\right|=\\
&=2\big|h\big|\quad\text{ for all }\;h\in\mathbb{R}\;\land\;h\ne0\;,
\end{align}

there exists

$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{\int_0^h\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\mathrm{d}x}{h}=0\;.$